# Replacing/removing "http:" from all image URI

Tags: javascript, http, firefox, replace, instagram

I am using [Instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/), and viewing it on FF 26.0 I'm getting this message 'Loading mixed (insecure) display content on a secure page "http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/4831ff30846511e3a4f412584b9218a9_8.jpg"'

Reading on Instafeed's github was this [suggestion](https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/42) that may solve the problem.

How do you reference the images coming through Instafeed to change from "http:" to "https:"?

Also, this may be a newb question but why do the example sites on the Instafeed site not bring up the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In your case, if you have another variable encompassing the instafeed images (like `document.getElementsByClassName('instafeed')` or something), use that instead of what I put in the first line here.*

```
var images = document.images || document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i].src.indexOf('https') < 0) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.substr(5, images[i].src.length);
    } else if (images[i].src.indexOf('https') === 0) {
        images[i].src = images[i].src.substr(6, images[i].src.length);
    }
}
```

## [Live Demonnnnnnnnstracionnnnnnnn](http://jsfiddle.net/2wwky/)

Comment: The images are being loaded as a url background in this <div id="instafeed" class="bg"></div> How do I specifically target these? Here is a codepen - http://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/bEtBg

Comment: I'm going to leave my default answer for anyone who lands on this page but for you:  `result.replace(/(http\:|https\:)/gmi, '');` just put that before `$("#instafeed").html(result);` and you're golden.  Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/k9Qgx/

Comment: I'm still getting that message and after inspecting the element it is still coming in as http: - http://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/detlw

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to say `result = result.replace(/(http\:|https\:)/gmi, '');`  Gotta actually assign the variable lol

Comment: Wonderful. Got the gray security padlock going on FF but Chrome 32 is giving an SSL Error and wont open the site (until I delete https:) Any idea why? Could that code be affecting it?

Comment: That code removes any bias of `http` vs `https`.  If there's something mixing, it's not there.  Look around the rest of the code for potential other non-https references.

Answer (score 1):

This is the common issue faced while referring to an external sources, when site is running under https protocol and we are referring to something under http protocol.

However, i would suggest you to use like below,

```
//distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/4831ff30846511e3a4f412584b9218a9_8.jpg
```

instead of

```
http://distilleryimage5.s3.amazonaws.com/4831ff30846511e3a4f412584b9218a9_8.jpg
```

We can ignore http or https and still able to access resource, be default it takes protocol under which site will be running.

**Another Example:**

```
//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js ---- will be as same as

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
```

Comment: How many images are we talking about here??? Will that be a static image or will it be added by users dynamically?

Comment: Dynamic, I suppose, as it will be coming in as a feed from Instagram. Here is a codepen - http://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/bEtBg They are loaded in as a background url. I think the max is 50 for Instafeed but I don't think I will have that many. I may have it run on two instances where one is an image slideshow and another is a set of thumbnails.